# Is there any way to nest groups hierarchically in Apple Contacts?

Tags: contacts

I have a huge number of contacts.  If there is absolutely no better way to organize them than a "flat file" list of groups, I may be forced to export each card individually just so I can have them in a directory structure.

The things I love about Apple Contacts are:

1. Integration with Mail.app.
2. Integration with Alfred PowerPack.
3. Pretty UI.

So this is really a two part question.

1. Is there any way to have hierarchically nested groups in Contacts.app?  And,
2. If not, is there any other application I could use that would give me this functionality without sacrificing other usability too much?

I have one possible not-so-great workaround myself, which I will post as a self-answer.  I'm hoping someone else has something better.

---

P.S.: Using El Capitan 10.11.6.

Answer (score 1):

The only possible "solution" I have (which isn't *really* a solution but it's what I will do if nothing better is suggested), is:

1. Take everyone I don't *routinely* contact, export their vCards individually (not in batches) (this is so that quicklook will work), and delete them from Address Book (a.k.a. Contacts).
2. Use Contacts for my every day common contacts, and use either a directory structure and Quick Look, or some third party app, to organize all the rest of my contacts.

This compromise preserves integration with Afred and Mail.app for common contacts, and allows me to better organize unusual contacts.  But I'd prefer nested contact groups directly in Contacts.app.